# Arduino UNO clone not showing up in Device Manager cant see it at all

Tags: arduino

For 2 days I was using Arduino clone with only UNO has written on it (MEGA328P) I uploaded my ir controlled servo cod and it was working powered only by USB connection. And when I tried powering it through 5v dc power supply it won't work at all. So after that window is not even reacting with windows plugged in beep when I plug it in my PC, can't see it at all in Device Manager and it normally blinks ON when I plug it in PC (even the L named LED blinks, I don't know what it is). When I press reset button the RX and TX LEDs are lighting up.

To add it all up i tried some fix from the internet to plugged in 19 V in dc power supply and my PC cable in (I used to do that but with some components on it) and my PC turned of instantly Arduino started smoking and now there is now a smudge on CH340G chip left (Maybe I have burnt it) but led ON and L still lights up when I plug it via USB.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on either the arduino beta or electronics stack exchange site - hardware issue not programming related. Probably https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ will be more friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have smoke then a smudge on the CH340G, then the USB chip on the board is destroyed and there is nothing you can do short of replacing it ( where 'it' is either the chip, if you are skilled and patient enough, or the board if not ). A chip can fail either open or closed circuit, so having some LEDs light ( but not blink ) doesn't mean much.

If the AVR chip also smoked, then I suspect you may have put the 19V on the 5V rail in which case both the AVR and the USB chips will be destroyed.

Comment: Thank you i ordered another one im just beginer in this and this is my lesson.

Comment: Hi Pete, when CH340G is broken, the RX and TX leds will always being turned on? in my case, this is happening and also the Arduino COM is not showing at Devices Manager.

Comment: @JoseLeles it's not impossible - a chip can fuse either open or closed circuit, especially if the leds are always on but different brightness.

Comment: I know that is not the focus, but, what can I do to my arduino being recognized again? I was thought that the CH340G was broken

Comment: @JoseLeles create a new question on the Arduino stack exchange with a photo of the lights